# ui.bootstrap rating directive doesn't seem to load

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I can't see the star rating input anywhere. Isn't it loaded? Am I using the directive wrong? Please help.

I have included the ui.bootstrao, JQuery, Bootstrapm and thought the directive should work right out of the box.

When I try to specify ui.bootstrap when defining the ng-app the ng-resource stop working.

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngResource','ui.bootstrap']);
```

test.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
<title>Test app/title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body role="document">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="PostIndexCtrl">
            <div class="row">
                <rating value="rate" max="5"></rating>
                <div ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-3">
                        {{item.name}} <img class="thumbnail" src="{{item.photo}}" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

service.js:

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngResource']);

app.factory("Post", function($resource) {
  return $resource("/api/item");
});

app.controller("PostIndexCtrl", function($scope, Post) {
  Post.get(function(data) {
//    alert(data.items);
      $scope.items = data.items;
  });
});
```

Comment: have you downloaded the `angular-ui` version with templates included?

Comment: I know this is an old question but when using ui-bootstrap I dont think there is any need for bootstrap.js. Also I think since bootstrap.js comes after ui-bootstrap in your arrangement above, it overrides ui-bootstrap(I'm not so sure). Anyways, I think you should just get rid of bootstrap.js all together. Also, download the ui-bootstrap with templates. "angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"

Answer (score 0):

This line in your html seems off to me:

```
<script src="components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Use:

```
angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js
```

or

```
angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js
```

instead of simply using:

```
angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js
```

which doesn't contain the templates.

If using bower, then install with:

```
bower install angular-bootstrap
```

Depending on your setup (and possibly .bowerrc file) the angular-bootstrap directory will, by default, be put in the directory:

```
bower_components/angular-bootstrap/   (or perhaps simply components/angular-bootstrap in your config)
```

where you can find the files mentioned above.

Comment: Already tried all sort of combinations of packages... tried your idea again and it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: did you ever find the solution to your problem?